# Checking video card load via command line

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics, nvidia

Is there a command like `cpustat` or `iostat` or `memstat`, but for the video card? Or some indication in `/proc` or `/sys`?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information. What is the card? Which operating system?

Comment: nvidia 8400gs card

Comment: @ChrisDown there is no standard for addressing GPUs?

Comment: AFAIL, via /dev ? , as far as i'd guess - only by script, or sysctl & script . I knew that my previous to Gentoo system, the Opensolaris had alot of *stat commands (can't remember about GPU)

Answer (score 1):

On some Intel cards, yes: [`intel_gpu_top`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~eugeni/intel-gpu-tools).